# IBackgroundtask deviceusetrigger thread hangs but not canceled neither crashed - windowsphone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, background, windows-phone-8.1

I have an IBackgroundtask triggered by a Deviceusetrigger in Windows phone 8.1 native.

This task is reading from the accelerometer every 500ms and performing some operations. At a certain point, it could be ten minutes or one hour or 5 hours the thread stops completely without a reason and it is not passing through the OnCanceled event so I'm not being canceled by the OS due to some policy.

The behavior is completely random. It should be no crash either because, there is no crash and no exception thrown.

I'm completely clueless on how to debug such a behavior, any idea is well accepted.

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _accelerometer = Accelerometer.GetDefault();

        if (null != _accelerometer)
        {
             if(moveIsActive)
            { 
                  uint minReportIntervalMsecs = _accelerometer.MinimumReportInterval;
                  _accelerometer.ReportInterval = minReportIntervalMsecs > 500 ? minReportIntervalMsecs : 500
                //accBckgrndSaved = "Report interval of accelerometer ms:" + _accelerometer.ReportInterval + Environment.NewLine + accBckgrndSaved;

                // Subscribe to accelerometer ReadingChanged events.
                _accelerometer.ReadingChanged += new TypedEventHandler<Accelerometer, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs>(ReadingChangedAsync);
            }

            // Take a deferral that is released when the task is completed.
            _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            // Get notified when the task is canceled.
            taskInstance.Canceled += new BackgroundTaskCanceledEventHandler(OnCanceled);

            // Store a setting so that the app knows that the task is running.
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[Constants.BCKSET_IS_BACKTASKACTIVE] = true;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Hello. Added the code. The code in the event handler does not crash and executes in less than 500ms and anyway it is protected for reentrance.